# mysql_select not working in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

So I am trying to select rows from a table called articles based on the ID. For some reason, I am having a problem with this and I am not sure why. The exact problem is that the script echoes a `FATAL ERROR` which means that my query is not working.

I updated the script to echo the error and here it is:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use
>   near ''Articles' WHERE 1' at line 1

Here is the code:

```
$id = 1;

$query =  mysql_query("SELECT * FROM 'Articles' WHERE ID = '$id'") or die("FATAL ERROR");
```

I tried just a simple select statement and that didn't work either:

```
$query =  mysql_query("SELECT * FROM 'Articles' WHERE 1") or die("FATAL ERROR");
```

Help is much appreciated, thanks!

Comment: What is the problem __exactly__?

Comment: What happens now? What is the error message?

Comment: What you get if run this query in phpmyadmin `SELECT * FROM \`Articles\` WHERE ID =1` ?

Comment: @Rishi It works just fine in PHP my admin.

Comment: @Anant Can you explain what the difference is? Thanks

Comment: Mysql_* functions are removed in php 7.0 and was already deprecated in php 5.5

Comment: @Anant I updated the post with the error.

Comment: @u_mulder I updated the post with the error.

Comment: Use  back-ticks around table name `Articles` instead of quotes

Comment: @Anant i tried putting back-ticks around the ID part but I still receive the same error as before: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ''Articles' WHERE `ID` = '1'' at line 1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of quotes use back-tics:-

```
$query =  mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `Articles` WHERE `ID` = $id") or die("FATAL ERROR");
```

Or

```
$query =  mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `Articles` WHERE 1") or die("FATAL ERROR");
```

Note:- Start using `mysqli_*` OR `PDO` instead of `mysql_*`, because `Mysql_*` functions are removed in `php 7.0` and was already deprecated in `php 5.5`

Also check column name `ID` is correct or not, because usually we use `id`.

Answer (score 2):

Although you should use mysqli or pdo as mysql is removed from php 7, however use backtick instead of single quotes arround table name

```
 $id = 1;

 $query =  mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `Articles` WHERE ID = '$id'") or die("FATAL ERROR");
```

Comment: Hi Rishi, this is what I get when I type that: Fatal error: Function name must be a string in /customers/2/1/9/fuzedfeed.com/httpd.www/scripts/php/uploadclick.php on line 17

Comment: Can you share all code and point line no 17 ?

Answer (score 2):

```
Change 'Articles' on `Articles`

$query =  mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `Articles` WHERE `ID` = '{$id}'") or die("FATAL ERROR");
```

if `Articles`.`ID` is integer,use this

```
$query =  mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `Articles` WHERE `ID` = ".$id) or die("FATAL ERROR");
```